In a C# Wpf application, how do you change a button's icon in a usercontrol dynamically
So in my application I have a usercontrol. It has among other things a button with an image defined as gemoetry data:
    <!--  Add new Item Button  -->
    <Button
        x:Name="createButton"
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        Margin="0,0,20,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding OpenNewWindowCommand}"
        Style="{StaticResource RoundAccentButton}">
        <!--  Icon  -->
        <Viewbox
            x:Name="createViewbox"
            Width="22"
            Height="22">
            <Path Data="{StaticResource NewTaskIcon}" Fill="{StaticResource OnAccent}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>

..and the Geometry data, which is placed in a ResourceDictionary, looks like this:
<!--  New Task Icon  -->
<PathGeometry x:Key="NewTaskIcon" Figures="M17 21.2188V17.4688H13.25V14.9688H17V11.2188H19.5V14.9688H23.25V17.4688H19.5V21.2188H17ZM0.75 17.5V15H3.25V17.5H0.75ZM5.75 17.5V15H10.8438C10.7812 15.4375 10.7552 15.8542 10.7656 16.25C10.776 16.6458 10.8125 17.0625 10.875 17.5H5.75ZM0.75 12.5V10H3.25V12.5H0.75ZM5.75 12.5V10H14.0625C13.5833 10.3333 13.151 10.7083 12.7656 11.125C12.3802 11.5417 12.0417 12 11.75 12.5H5.75ZM0.75 7.5V5H3.25V7.5H0.75ZM5.75 7.5V5H20.75V7.5H5.75ZM0.75 2.5V0H3.25V2.5H0.75ZM5.75 2.5V0H20.75V2.5H5.75Z" />

The problem is that I of course do not want to set the PathData as a hardcoded value in the usercontrol, but instead set it where the usercontrol is used. For instance, I use this usercontrol, called SearchItems, in another View called TaskView.xaml like this:
<UserControl
x:Class="myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.Views.TaskView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.UserControls"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.ViewModels"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="435"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TaskViewViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Border Width="435" Background="{StaticResource TaskListBackground}">

        <uc:SearchItems />

    </Border>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--  Task Viewer  -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

.
.
.
What I would like to do is to access the Viewbox with the PathData to change the icon depending on where the usercontrol is used. I thought I could do that by defining a DependencyProperty, let's say we call it PathData, and then set it in the Views where I use the usercontrol, i.e. something like this (below is a view defined as a usercontrol which uses the SearchItems usercontrol):
<UserControl
x:Class="myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.Views.TaskView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.UserControls"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.ViewModels"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="435"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TaskViewViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Border Width="435" Background="{StaticResource TaskListBackground}">

        <uc:SearchItems PathData="{StaticResource NewTaskIcon}" />

    </Border>

..or by simply defining a property in the code-behind for the usercontrol called PathData:
        public Geometry PathData { get; set; }

and then in the usercontrol's xaml code have it done like this:
        <!--  Add new Item Button  -->
    <Button
        x:Name="createButton"
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        Margin="0,0,20,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding OpenNewWindowCommand}"
        Style="{StaticResource RoundAccentButton}">
        <!--  Icon  -->
        <Viewbox
            x:Name="createViewbox"
            Width="22"
            Height="22">
            <Path Data="{Binding PathData}" Fill="{StaticResource OnAccent}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>

..and then in the Views that use the usercontrol just use the same syntax as above, i.e.:
<UserControl
x:Class="myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.Views.TaskView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.UserControls"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myTaskManager.UI.Wpf.MVVM.ViewModels"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="435"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TaskViewViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Border Width="435" Background="{StaticResource TaskListBackground}">

        <uc:SearchItems PathData="{StaticResource NewTaskIcon}" />

    </Border>

..where I set the PathData dynamically, but neither of these ways seem to work. What would be the best way to accomplish this?
Any answer pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Peter

The UserControl should expose a dependency property (which can be data-bound or set by a Style). The internal Binding would be Data="{Binding PathData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}".

Since this property defines an icon in a Button, or more generally the Content of a Button, you may want to declare it as object and bind the Button's Content like <Button ... Content={Binding Binding ButtonIcon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}/>

Instead of creating UserControl which hosts Button, creating custom Button which inherits Button and has is added with Geometry dependency property would be better. That way, you can directly access the properties of Button from outside without relaying the values through UserControl.

@emoacht "It has among other things a button with an image ..."

@Clemens I see. Exactly.

@emoacht The idea you have is good, but like I stated in my question, and that Clemens points out, it's a user control that has a few other controls as well, and I have to set a few of the properties for each of the controls in the custom user control dynamically.

The UserControl should expose a dependency property in order to make it bindable and settable by a Style.
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconDataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IconData), typeof(Geometry), typeof(SearchItems));

public Geometry IconData
{
    get => (Geometry)GetValue(IconDataProperty);
    set => SetValue(IconDataProperty, value);
}

It would be used in a Path element in the control's XAML via a RelativeSource Binding. Note that a Viewbox is not required.
<Button Width="40" Height="40" ...>
    <Path Width="22" Height="22"
          Data="{Binding IconData,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
          Fill="{StaticResource OnAccent}"
          Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Button>

Now you could assign an icon like
<uc:SearchItems IconData="{StaticResource NewTaskIcon}" />


Thanks a bunch!! It made my day :). I had the same DP implemented but had totally missed the RelativeSource part in the Xaml. Works like a charm now :D

There should have been data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debugged the application.
